# Examples of mandatory type deduction in C++

Tags: c++, types, auto, type-deduction

[Google's C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html) at some point states:

> There are several contexts in which C++ allows (or even requires) types to be deduced by the compiler.

What are some examples of mandatory type deduction?

Comment: Probably talking about lambdas or other unnameable types. E.G. if you have a `private` nested class/struct, you can still return it, but its type must be deduced, since you can't name it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example is initialisation of a lambda variable. The type of the lambda is anonymous, therefore it cannot be named explicitly and must be deduced:

```
auto var = [capture]{};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```
struct {
    int x, y;
} g_xy;
```

Here `g_xy` is a global variable of unnamed type. If you try to return it for example you have to let the compiler deduce the return type of the function because you cannot name it:

```
auto foo()
{
    return g_xy;
}
```

Although possible unnamed types (except lamdas) are rarely useful and used.

Comment: @eerorika I think it does.

Comment: Fair enough. Then my comment is irrelevant :)

Comment: @eerorika I am not 100% sure, but it seems logical to me. Anyway fun fact since C++20 you can have `decltype([] { return 24;}) l;   return l();`

Comment: Cool. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

The style guide gives several examples where the compiler does automatic type deduction. The most obvious case is whenever you use the `auto` keyword, introduced with C++11. [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is a placeholder for an actual type. Whenever you use `auto` the compiler will deduce the type from: the type of expression used to intialise a variable; the trailing type or type of return expression of a function.

Normally you would declare a variable like this:

```
int i = 0;
```

where you specify the type `int` for the variable `i`. However, in modern C++ you could declare variables without specifying their type and the compiler will deduce their types automatically:

```
auto a = 42;         // a is an int
auto& b = a;         // b is an int&
auto c = b;          // c is an int
auto d{42};          // d is an int, not a std::initializer_list<int>
auto v = {1, 2, 3};  //v is a std::initializer_list<int>
```

Other examples include a named lambda function:

```
auto lower = [] (const char c) { return tolower(c); };
```

and in C++14 onward, a generic lambda where both the return type and lambda parameters can be `auto`:

```
auto add = [](const auto a, const auto b) { return a + b; }
```

One thing to note is that `auto` is a placeholder for type, not for `const`, `volatile` or reference specifers.

Some advantages of using `auto` include:

- variable is always initialised
- ensure the correct type is used without any implicit conversion
- less typing and concern for actual type

Answer (score 0):

And yet another example - type of generic lambdas with `auto` arguments can not be specified.

```
auto lam = [](auto v) { }
```

There is no way to specify type of `v` in invocation of lambda.

Comment: fun fact: since C++20 you can write: `auto lam = [] <class T> (T v) { return x + 24; };`

Comment: @bolov most certainly you can.